# suggestions(recommendations) in the solr search results

Tags: solr

I am using solr to search contents of the PDF files that I have indexed. I am considering the whole content of the file as content field. Now I need some suggestions in the result as how we get in online shopping sites. Along with the solr result, I need information such as most searched text or something like you can also find: blah blah. And I also need the result to be displayed in the order of most selected answers for the searched text.
Please can anyone brief me on this? I am new to solr. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you ask this question over and over again. without even trying to adopt it or describe your need more properly. Suggestions could be done easily in Solr. Most searched text is more about statistics

Comment: can you please tell me the way for getting suggestions? thanks a lot

Comment: does your understanding of suggestion is the same as in Solr terminology, where it mean more of autocomplete?

Comment: autocomplete and also like how we get in the online sites.. you can also find.... The order of the results should be in the order of selected result in the past